# Where is the Postgresql config file: 'postgresql.conf' on Windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm receiving this message but I can't find the `postgresql.conf` file:

```
OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on host "???" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

On my machine:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\postgresql.conf
```

Comment: I don't have that folder even though I ran the installer from http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

Comment: psycopg is used to connect to the Database server, it isn't the Database server itself.  You want to install the server portion from here: http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows

Comment: Just a side note: it usually not a very good idea to put application data into c:\Program Files

Comment: For PostgreSQL 9.2 and probably the earlier versions in the 9.x series, it is located at the much more appropriate location of C:\ProgramData\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\postgresql.conf (at least with Windows 7 anyway).

Answer (score 40):

`postgresql.conf` is located **in PostgreSQL's data directory**. The data directory is configured during the setup and the setting is saved as `PGDATA` entry in `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\pg_env.bat`, for example

```bat
    @ECHO OFF
    REM The script sets environment variables helpful for PostgreSQL
    
    @SET PATH="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\bin";%PATH%
    @SET PGDATA=D:\PostgreSQL\<version>\data
    @SET PGDATABASE=postgres
    @SET PGUSER=postgres
    @SET PGPORT=5432
    @SET PGLOCALEDIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\share\locale
```

Alternatively you can query your database with `SHOW config_file;` if you are a superuser.

Comment: This answer gave me some errors, so I found a working one here (version 9.3 64 bit with windows 8 64 bit) http://stackoverflow.com/a/17249527/2327328

Comment: @philshem What kind of errors? `postgresql.conf`should be findable with this description.

Comment: for every line: 'syntax error in file "C:/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postgresql.conf" line 1, near token "@"'

Comment: @philshem the example in my answer is just the content of the mentioned `pg_env.bat` and not intended for use in `postgresql.conf`. The `postgresql.conf` file should exist in the PGDATA directory and looks like this: [postgresql.conf.sample](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample;hb=HEAD)

Comment: This is a more generic answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

You can find it by  following this path

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data
```

Answer (score 1):

On  my machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 6.1-20121026-233219\PostgreSQL\data
```

Answer (score 1):

you will get postgressql.conf file

C:/programfiles/postgressql/14/data
you will also get the pg_hba to check username password

Answer (score 0):

PGDATA is assumed as ConfigDir under Postgresql, this works under docker and normal installation as well, this is default configuration until not changed explicitly.

on my docker PGDATA is configure as "/var/lib/postgresql/data" hence all configuration can be found under this directory.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'       # use data in another directory
                # (change requires restart)
#hba_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_hba.conf' # host-based authentication file
                # (change requires restart)
#ident_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_ident.conf' # ident configuration file
                # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
#external_pid_file = ''         # write an extra PID file
                # (change requires restart)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your Postgres global config file using the following path:

- Replace  with the Postgres version you have installed.

  C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL<version>\data

This is usually the default location at installation.

However, if you are still unable to locate the file using the path try using file search in Windows.