# Debug PostgreSQL function using pgAdmin

Tags: debugging, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin

I refer [this](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/214-Using-PgAdmin-PLPgSQL-Debugger.html)  to enable  the debugger in the PostgreSQL server in order to debugging the plpgsql function by stepping through the code using pgadmin.

I have already set `shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll'` in the `postgresql.conf`, run `pldbgapi.sql` , and restarted the server.

These steps should have been run successfully and `plugin_debugger.dll` should be loaded successfully as can be verified by using the command `show shared_preload_libraries`, and I can see the debugging option in the context menu with a right click on a function in pgAdmin.

[image]

When choosing "Debugging" --> Debug, a window pops up to allow me to enter the values for the input parameters. But after that, when I press `OK`, it does not respond at all.

[image]

Any ideas or did I miss something in the setup of the debugger on the server?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.3 and pgAdmin 1.14

Comment: +1 good question. I don't know why it fails, though. If nothing turns up, you can always send your question to the pgAdmin support list: pgadmin-support@postgresql.org (include a link to your question here). See the [list archive here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgadmin-support/2011-10/threads.php).

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the link , I have already sent the questions to the pgAdmin support

Comment: Answer !!! http://archives.postgresql.org/pgadmin-support/2011-10/msg00052.php

Comment: And you are running as super user? According to the site you refer to one needs to be super user in order for it to work.

Comment: Yes , I am the super user account . The same problem exists even I use the `postgres` account that is created by default

Comment: What platform are you running on? Looks like a flavor of Linux?

Comment: Duh, Windows... Okay, so here's another probably duh question: did you run the pldbgapi.sql script _before_ or _after_ restarting the server? If it was before, you could try restarting the server again...

Comment: Er, re-running the pldbgapi.sql script (not restarting the server - the script is supposed to be run _after_ the server restart).

Comment: @leanne : Here is the flow I try : 1 . Install a new PostgreSQL 8.3 server on the window platform . 2. After installation , PostgreSQL starts automatically . 3. Change the configuration of PostgreSQL to enable `plugin_debugger.dll` plug-in  .4 Restart the server and connect to the server using pgAdmin to run `pldbgapi.sql` .5.Restart the server .  So , the  `pldbgapi.sql` is already run after the server restart

Comment: Strange.. I Tried it as well and I faced the same problem. I think it's a bug.

Comment: I know this is obvious, but have you set breakpoints? Can you check if your function runs (by logging, or inserting something in a table)?

Comment: To @Alex and Mr. Pallazzo :  The functions can run properly . And for the `Set breakpoints` options, it open a dialog saying that `Waiting for another session to invoke the add() function`. But of course , it has no respond though I invoke  add() function in other transactions . I think it may due to `plugin_debugger.dll` has some problems to listen to the incoming debugging request. I tried again to enable the debugger in other window machine and it can work. So I think I setup the debugger correctly .

Comment: @KenChan If you figured out how to do the setup correctly, answer your question and mark it as answered.

Comment: pldbgapi.sql script can be found in share\extension\pldbgapi--1.0.sql path.

Comment: please see suggestion for install it on linux in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534998/where-can-i-get-pldbgapi-sql-in-order-to-install-the-debugger-for-postgresql/42045979#42045979) question

Answer (score 8):

You have to enable debugging in two places. On PGAdmin and on the database itself.  That article you referenced does a wonderful job explaining it but there were some nuances.

**PGAdmin**

When updating your `postgresql.conf` file to load the debugging library, I was [running PGAdmin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4465482/316857) so the file was here:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\postgresql.conf
```

And the path to the `plugin_debugger.dll` was actually

```
$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll
```

not

```
$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll
```

as specified in the article.  So your `postgresql.conf` would need a line like this

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'
```

Search for the actual .dll if you're in doubt.  If you're on Linux the file you'll be looking for is `plugin_debugger.so`.  Don't forget that changing the `postgresql.conf` file will require a restart for the change to take effect.

**PostgreSQL Database**

Assuming you're running your PostgreSQL database on a Linux server [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jhngrant/c1787346fcb4b0e3001a) does an excellent job at explaining how to download the dependencies for enabling debugging.  Make sure you're running as root when you install.

The part that's easy to miss is issuing the command against the actual database you want to debug.  For newer versions on PostgreSQL all you'll need to do is this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pldbgapi;
```

If that doesn't return an error, you should be good to go.

Some additional things of note:

- As mentioned above, you can only debug when running as a super user account
- From [their docs](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/debugger.html) you can only debug pl/pgsql functions.  So if your function says something like `LANGUAGE c` PGAdmin won't even show a right-click Debug menu option when you select the function.  Look for something that has `LANGUAGE plpgsql` and the Debug menu should show.

Answer (score 2):

Ken,

Have you tried pgAdmin 1.8 to rule out issue with PgAdmin 1.14/ PostgreSQL 8.3 interaction.  It's been a while since I've used 8.3 and for the article I wrote -- which you are referring to, I was testing with 1.14/ PostgreSQL 9.1 so it could very well be an issue with the interaction with older version.  Unfortunately I don't have a 8.3 anymore to test with.

I vaguely remember having the issue you had once, but it was when I had another shared library in my postgresql.conf in addition to the pldebugger.  Can't remember which one that was, but removing the other shared library fixed my issue.

Hope some of these suggestions help,
Regina

Comment: Thanks Regina . I tried to use pgAdmin 1.14 , 1.12 and 1.8 with the PostgreSQL server 8.13.16 , and the problem still exists . But in my office 's PC , I tried to use pgAdmin 1.12 with the PostgreSQL server 8.13.5 ,and it works very well.  I will try to use the latest version of PostgreSQL 9.1 if I am free

Comment: I wonder if it's some sort of antivirus thing blocking it then.

Comment: Thanks Regina  for the suggestion . But I disabled the antivirus (which is Avira AntiVir) and the window firewall ,  but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Make sure the *only* shared lib you´re loading in the postgres.conf is the debugger.
Nothing else. Not even the profiler.
If you get a SSL error when trying to debug a function, reconnect to the server.