# Where can I get pldbgapi.sql in order to install the debugger for postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgadmin

I am trying to install the debugger for postgresql on Linux so I can use pgAdmin to debug my functions. I've set up my **postgresql.conf** file. However, I can't find **pldbgapi.sql**.

Postgresql is installed at **/usr/pgsql-9.2/**. The directory **/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/** exists, but **/usr/pgsql-9.2/share/contrib** does not exist. Where can I find the file or download it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've found out it works if I run the contents of this file

```
share\extension\pldbgapi--1.0.sql
```

There is also this readme for the extension which mentions a different installation process, I haven't tried it

http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pldebugger.git;a=blob_plain;f=README.pldebugger;hb=54d993c04809da7cda79013a55b679a615c7dce1

Comment: so once you find that sql file, just copy paste into pgadmin and run?

Answer (score 3):

Excelent aport, only:

- Edit your postgresql.conf file, and modify the shared_preload_libraries config
  option to look like:

  shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger'
- Restart PostgreSQL for the new setting to take effect.
- Run the following command in the database or databases that you wish to
  debug functions in:

  CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
- Restart PostgreSQL for the new setting to take effect.
  Finally you can debugg!!

I used in Postgres 9.4

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Am I right? This is not a forum, you should only write an answer when it answers the question, otherwise you have to comment!

Comment: @limoragni: the question says: "in order to install the debugger". Well, This answer explains the proper way to do that. The original asker seems to want to locate the file in order to execute its content. The first comment in the accepted answer also seems to understand that he ought to do the same thing. The real answer is that he doesn't need to locate where the `.sql` file is nor to run it manually; VictorMartinez explains the proper steps to accomplish his purpose. More precisely, the `CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;` part seems to be what he needs.

Answer (score 3):

This is included with EnterpriseDB distributive. You can download it on pgFoundry. [here is a link](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/edb-debugger/)

Also git repo is available.

```
git clone git://git.postgresql.org/git/pldebugger.git
cd pldebugger
export USE_PGXS=1
make
make install
```

Edit postgresql.conf

```
vim /path/to/postgresql.conf
```

add:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'plugin_debugger'
```

Restart postgres, connect to db and call:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
```

I use it on postgreql 9.5, works well.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04 i had problems with make: "fatal error: gssapi/gssapi.h: No such file or directory" which i resolved by installing libkrb5-dev ( sudo apt-get install libkrb5-dev)

Comment: I had the following error message: "plpgsql_debugger.c:12:10: fatal error: postgres.h: No such file or directory" The reason was, that I also had a higher postgres version installed (13) but was running 12. Removing 13 did solve that. ('sudo apt remove postgresql-13')

Answer (score 2):

For postgres 12, you should install this package using this commad:

```
apt-get install postgresql-12-pldebugger
```

There is no need to change the postgresql.conf file.
You should also create this extension in the database that you will use for debugging:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
```

I am using PGAdmin 4 for debugging PL/SQL procedures.

Comment: hi, will this work on AWS RDS as well ? Any idea on this?