# How to use Debugger in PostgreSQL PG-ADMIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I was used Oracle SQL developer in that debugger is worked fine after `Grant Debugger` but I am now using PostgreSQL PG-ADMIN and I am trying to use debug function but debug is not work.

Is there any grant or any other procedure?

[image: debugImage]

I also refer:

[Debug PostgreSQL function using pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865615/debug-postgresql-function-using-pgadmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable debugging in two places. On PGAdmin and on the database itself.  That article you referenced does a wonderful job explaining it but there were some nuances.

**PGAdmin**

When updating your `postgresql.conf` file to load the debugging library, I was [running PGAdmin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4465482/316857) so the file was here:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\data\postgresql.conf
```

And the path to the `plugin_debugger.dll` was actually

```
$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll
```

not

```
$libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll
```

as specified in the article.  So your `postgresql.conf` would need a line like this

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'
```

Search for the actual .dll if you're in doubt.  If you're on Linux the file you'll be looking for is `plugin_debugger.so`.  Don't forget that changing the `postgresql.conf` file will require a restart for the change to take effect.

**PostgreSQL Database**

Assuming you're running your PostgreSQL database on a Linux server [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jhngrant/c1787346fcb4b0e3001a) does an excellent job at explaining how to download the dependencies for enabling debugging.  Make sure you're running as root when you install.

The part that's easy to miss is issuing the command against the actual database you want to debug.  For newer versions on PostgreSQL all you'll need to do is this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pldbgapi;
```

If that doesn't return an error, you should be good to go.

Some additional things of note:

- As mentioned above, you can only debug when running as a super user account
- From [their docs](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.8/debugger.html) you can only debug pl/pgsql functions.  So if your function says something like `LANGUAGE c` PGAdmin won't even show a right-click Debug menu option when you select the function.  Look for something that has `LANGUAGE plpgsql` and the Debug menu should show.