# Connecting cakephp 2.0 with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.0 and a wamp server. I have enabled the pdo of postgres in the php and i tried connecting to Postgres. However it still says that there is an error. My login and password is also double confirmed.

Below is codes for the database.php file:

```
public $default = array(
  'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
  'persistent' => false,
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '5432',
  'login' => 'postgres',
  'password' => 'password',
  'database' => 'Test',
  'schema' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'encoding' => ''
 );
```

I even tried this:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'port' => '5432',
    'login' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'Test',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => ''
  );
```

My pga_hba.config file is:

```
 TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5
```

In the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.9\ext

I have both:

```
php_pdo_pgsql.dll
php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

My config Postgres config file is :

```
listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per 
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directory = ''     # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)
```

I check php info and I still found that that the pgsql was not there. I am using wamp server.

```
[PostgresSQL]
; Allow or prevent persistent links.
; http://php.net/pgsql.allow-persistent
pgsql.allow_persistent = On

; Detect broken persistent links always with pg_pconnect().
; Auto reset feature requires a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.auto-reset-persistent
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off

; Maximum number of persistent links.  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-persistent
pgsql.max_persistent = -1

; Maximum number of links (persistent+non persistent).  -1 means no limit.
; http://php.net/pgsql.max-links
pgsql.max_links = -1

; Ignore PostgreSQL backends Notice message or not.
; Notice message logging require a little overheads.
; http://php.net/pgsql.ignore-notice
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0

; Log PostgreSQL backends Noitce message or not.
; Unless pgsql.ignore_notice=0, module cannot log notice message.
; http://php.net/pgsql.log-notice
pgsql.log_notice = 0
```

I already did this in my php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

Comment: As always, the error message would be instrumental for helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for my problem This guy is very useful

http://tutology.net/category/mysql/install-postgresql-and-phppgadmin-windows-wamp

Basically i Copied libpq.dll from wamp\bin\php\phpX.X.X to wamp\bin\apache\ApacheX.X.XX\bin

Comment: I follow your answer and I have successfully. But I have a attention. We have to copy this file to Apache/bin before we enable in php.ini and restart server. If we don't the apache server will not able to start.

Answer (score 2):

A shot in the dark: Is the name of the database `Test` or `test`? Unquoted identifiers are cast to lower case in PostgreSQL. [The manual about that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Next shot in the dark: You are connecting to `localhost`. This is not a local connection via Unix domain socket. For this to work the database must be set up to listen to TCP/IP connections. So you need in your `postgresql.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

.. and restart.

Also, your `pg_hba.conf` settings need to allow the connection. Could be a problem [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9344040/939860).
Start by reading the chapter [Connection Settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) in the fine manual.

But I am done guessing now. You **need** to provide the error message.

Comment: where is the config file? I saved it to C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4

Comment: is it here: C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4\data

Comment: Yes, for version 8.4 under windows, it should be: `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data\postgresql.conf`. [See this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4465475/939860).

Comment: in cakephp it just says that there is an error connecting to database. I have added more info

Comment: @madi Then I am fresh out of ideas, sorry. I am no expert with cakephp, just PostgreSQL.