# postgresql ,apache,cake php

Tags: php, apache, cakephp

Hi i am trying to connect Postgresql with Apache 24.apache 24 for localhost runs on my webpage,but when i try to connect to the database it gives me this error.

> Datasource class Postgres could not be found.

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost:81',
    'login' => 'postgres',
    'password' => '786323',
    'database' => 'Blog',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

what m i doing wrong???

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639080/connecting-cakephp-2-0-with-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Check that your php has the [pgsql pdo driver extension](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php) and that it is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The question was not clear.

But you can refer this website:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql

I think

```
'datasource' => 'Database/Postgres',
```

should be

```
'data source' => 'Database/Postgres',
```