# FATAL: configuration file postgresql.conf contains errors

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-13

I used postgresql almost a year on my local.
Yesterday I used it and after I update the windows. Today I can not connect to the postgresql. It gives the below error:

```
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

After that I tried restart/start postgresql from services and it gives another error:

```
The postgresql-x64-13 service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.
```

When I check the event viewer I saw this error:

```
2023-11-17 10:56:01.911 +03 [20256] FATAL:  configuration file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/data/postgresql.conf" contains errors
```

I did not change any config, how can I fix this issue? I also share the properties:

[image]

Config file: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data\postgresql.conf
WeTransfer link of config file: (I can not share the link)
[image]

Comment: Perhaps, the update routine failed and tried to apply a diff to the config file. Could you post the contents of the config file?

Comment: Does the config file exist? This question/answers may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730405/postgres-installation-error-reading-file-postgresql-conf

Comment: @erny the config file is in the question, and the change date has not changed.

Comment: "the config file is in the question" -no, it's not. Theres only a link to that file. Please share all details **in text form**

Comment: The file has 780 lines, the text limit of question box exceeded. Thats why I added the we transfer link. And also if you want to check a specific part of the config file, I can share. Or do you have another suggestion for me to share?

Comment: @MRSeen: I was able to download the config file. Could you check if you have a file "postgresql.auto.conf" ? I've looked into your file, it seems ok. Could you comment the lines step by step, I would start with the lines starting with 'lc_'. (I really can't test the file, because I have no windows, and neither turkish character sets configured.)

Comment: I comment them, but this time my .net application gives an error: Npgsql.PostgresException: 'XX000: database native is not compatible with operating system

Comment: Please add **all* clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: do you have this `lc_messages = 'Turkish_Turkey.1254'` on your .conf file.