# Forgotten psql Password: sql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "username"

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

I have created a database with a database user and password using the psql shell. Now, I want to create another additional database using the shell. However, when I enter psql in Windows Command Prompt, I am prompted to enter my password, which I have forgotten.

```
$ psql
$ psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
```

I want to keep my other databases I created 100% in tact and functioning but would like to create another database in addition. What should I do to accomplish this without messing up the other database?

Comment: Did you know the pass for postgres user? If you know just use that and after that you `alter` the password for user you forgot the pass..

Comment: Which password you forgot? Password you have provided during installation or the password of the particular user you have created as database owner.

Comment: I know the password for my database but do not the password for my postgres user

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reset your forgotten password? Check below questions.

- [I forgot postgres password.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845998/i-forgot-the-password-i-entered-during-postgres-installation)
- [Where is `pg_hba.conf` in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465475/where-is-the-postgresql-config-file-postgresql-conf-on-windows)